# Comparing 2 strings with number values JS

Tags: javascript

Im trying to check to see if current time is lower than time that is responded from an API. Problem is they are both strings. The API response contains characters such as : and -, so parseInt is not working (at least that's my theory why its not working)

```
var d = new Date();
var hour = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth() +1;
var day = d.getDate();
var seconds = d.getSeconds();
var time = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+' '+hour+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
```

`time` returns

```
"2016-11-7 15:48:2"
```

API Response is

```
"2016-11-07 20:06:00"
```

I have confirmed they are both `strings`

```
time < APIresponse
```

Always returns false
Are there any known solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried getTime function??

Comment: `time.localeCompare(APIResponse)` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: new Date('2016-11-7 15:48:2').getTime() will return you -  1478513882000 which is number then you can compare

Comment: @Chetan using that date constructor is not safe

Comment: But what to do with the API response being a string?

Comment: @Phil - can you please elaborate on this... it will really help me in future.

Comment: @Chetan see the note under the **`dateString`** parameter ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

Comment: You should change your API to return an ISO 8601 formatted string which is generally safe to use in the `Date` constructor. Then you can compare the dates naturally

Comment: thanks @Phil, it is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

#### Preface: Timezone

Your current code assumes that the date/time you're getting from the API is in "local time," because you're comparing it with the current date/time in the browser's local timezone. APIs frequently provide date/times in UTC rather than "local" time, so beware of that assumption and double-check it.

#### If you want to do it at the string level

...you need to ensure when building `time` that you zero-pad the numbers, so for instance not just `7` for the day of the month, but `07`. Then you'll end up with strings that have the fields in a valid comparable order (because the most significant field [year] is first, and the least significant field [seconds] is last), so a lexicographic comparison of the strings is valid.

So for instance, you'd create `time` like this:

```
var time = pad(year, 4) + '-' + pad(month, 2) + '-' + pad(day, 2) + ' ' + pad(hour, 2) + ':' + pad(minutes, 2) + ':' + pad(seconds, 2);
```

...where `pad` is a function you define that adds as many `0`s as needed to ensure the string is as long as the second argument defines.

Then you can do:

```
if (time < timeStringFromAPI)
```

Note: If the API's response is giving you the date/time in UTC rather than local time, you'll need to use the UTC version of the accessor functions (e.g., `getUTCHours`, `getUTCFullYear`, etc.) rather than the ones you're using, which are for local time.

#### If you want to do it at the date level

...then you need to convert the date you're getting from the API to a `Date`. It's *almost* in a form you can reliable parse on modern browsers, 
but not quite; some browsers will parse that string as local time, others as UTC.

**If** you're sure it's in local time, then the best thing to do is split it into its parts and use the multipart `Date` constructor:

```
var parts = timeStringFromAPI.split(/[-:]/);
var apiDate = new Date(
    +parts[0],     // Year
    +parts[1] - 1, // Month
    +parts[2],     // Day
    +parts[3],     // Hours
    +parts[4],     // Minutes
    +parts[5]      // Seconds
);
```

**If** you're sure it's in UTC, then you can either do the above but with `new Date(Date.UTC(...))` rather than just `new Date(...)`, or you can put the string into the [JavaScript date/time format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) and parse that:

```
var apiDate = new Date(timeStringFromAPI.replace(" ", "T") + "Z");
```

That takes the `"2016-11-07 20:06:00"` and changes it to `"2016-11-07T20:06:00Z"`, which can reliably be parsed on all non-obsolete browsers.

Then you can do

```
if (new Date() < apiDate) {
```

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
   var curDate = new Date();
```

then compare in this way

```
  if (new Date(yourdate) <= curDate)
   {
  something...
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var d1 = "2016-11-7 15:48:2";
var d2 = "2016-11-07 20:06:00";

if (new Date(d1) < new Date(d2)) {
    alert('true')
}
```